# PHP - Remove any numbers before any letters

Tags: php, regex, numbers, expression

I am processing addresses, but I just want to remove the Street Number, eg

`123 Fake St`

I use the following regular expression `/[^a-z ]/i'` which works fine and results in

`Fake St`

However sometimes I have addresses such as

`M4 Western Distributor Fwy`

How would I keep the M4 part? Because if I run my regular expression it turns into

`M Western Distributor Fwy`

Any help would be appreciated, cheers

Comment: is it just the start or you want to replace the inner ones too? what do you want the result to be when you give "123. street 5. apartment" as input?

Comment: @GabrielSantos most of the questions I've asked I answered myself lol, I've fixed it up now.

Comment: @tpaksu just the outter ones, I think Apartments should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
/^[0-9 ]+(?=[^\d]+)/i
```

This matches all numbers that is followed by anything other than numbers, test:

```
$subject = '123 Fake St';
var_dump(preg_replace('/^[0-9 ]+(?=[^\d]+)/i', '', $subject));

$subject = 'M4 Western Distributor Fwy';
var_dump(preg_replace('/^[0-9 ]+(?=[^\d]+)/i', '', $subject));
```

Output:

```
string(7) "Fake St"
string(26) "M4 Western Distributor Fwy"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
/\b[^a-z ]+\b/i
```

as your regex instead. This will match any occurrence of one or more non-letters that are bounded by a word boundary. Actually, if you only want to remove numbers you should use

```
/\b[\d]+\b/
```

Answer (score 1):

Some times non regex methods are also worthy

```
$test="123 Fake St";
    $arr=explode(" ",$test);
    if(ctype_digit($arr[0])){
        $test=str_replace($arr[0],"",$test);
    }
echo $test;
```

Comment: Thanks, but sometimes numbers maybe have spaces in them